# Getting the List<Object> for every key out of a Map<String, List<Object>> (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I need to sort every value of a Map with multiple objects in each value, but I am struggling to see how. My Map looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, List<Carrier>> carriers_list;
```

I already have a Custom Comparator set up to compare a List of my objects.

```
static class CarrierComparator implements Comparator<Carrier> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Carrier c1, Carrier c2) {
            return c1.get_name().compareTo(c2.get_name());
        }
    }
```

I can use this Comparator like so:

```
List<Carrier> carrierList = getAllCarriers();
Collections.sort(carrierList, new CustomComparators.CarrierComparator());
```

How can I get each List for every key in my Map?

Comment: Don't you rather mean "How can I get the `List<Carrier>` containing all `Carrier`s from my `Map<String,List<Carrier>>` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Then please edit the question, the current name is misleading.I'll answer it in a bit.

Comment: Alright, I edited it appropriately. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, seeing the answer you validated, it seems that I had misunderstood your issue and made you edit the question inappropriately. You actually simply wanted to iterate on the map's values, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the map's values:

```
CustomComparators.CarrierComparator comparator = new CustomComparators.CarrierComparator();
for (List<Carrier> l : carriers_list.values())
    Collections.sort(l, comparator);
```

Comment: If that is the answer, everyone else misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4):

To get all the values combined in one big list:

```
List<Carrier> values = map.values().stream()
                                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can do the sorting in the same expression:

```
List<Carrier> values = map.values().stream()
                                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                                   .sorted(comparator)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is around the likes of :

```
Map<Object,List<Object>> multimap = new HashMap<>();
    multimap.values().stream()                     // stream the values
    .flatMap(List::stream)                         // stream on the items in every list
    .sorted(CarrierComparator::compare)            // use your comparator
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                 // collect in a single List
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic code which shows how to extract all Carrier objects into one list and then sort them.

```
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
    List<Carrier> carriers = new ArrayList<Carrier>();
    for (String key : keys) {
        List<Carrier> temp = map.get(key);
        for (Carrier carrier : temp) {
            carriers.add(carrier);
        }
    }
    carriers.sort(new CarrierComparator());
```

"carriers" will contain sorted list of objects.